# Changing the Windows 7 taskbar location when the number of connected monitors changes

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar

For my workstation I use a laptop connected to several monitors: I have a taskbar at the bottom on each monitor (using DisplayFusion for the non-primary monitors). Sometimes I take the laptop out and use it without any external monitor: I would like to have the taskbar at the left. Is it possible to changing the Windows 7 taskbar location when the number of connected monitors?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

Set the primary desktop to be anything but your laptop, and set the taskbar to that monitor as well.

As you move out and disconnect any external monitor, windows will change the primary monitor and thus move your taskbar. Plugging it back in should move the taskbar back to the primary monitor.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have mentioned the expected taskbar location. I've edited my question to add this information.

Comment: Should still work. If the taskbar is on the laptop it doesn't matter. But it may be a problem with DisplayFusion. Have you actually tested this?

Comment: But I need a taskbar at the bottom on each monitor (laptop included) in the case the laptop is connected.